# show the most recent date of a datagridview

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

i have a datagridview with a column filled with dates, i want a textbox to show only the most recent one, what i did wasis to put a very early date in the textbox(01/01/0000) and then run the whole datagrid in a for loop but it gives me this error

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

```
 dataGridView1.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value.ToString());
            DateTime date1 = DateTime.ParseExact(dataRecente.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);
            if (date > date1)
            {
                dataRecente.Text = Convert.ToString(date);
            }
        }
```

Comment: First, a DGV is a poor choice of data container.  A `DataTable` or `List<T>` can be a DataSource which would allow filtering with one line of code.  Next, there is no reason to parse the date over and over in a loop - its the same date. Also, a DateTimePicker would eliminate the need to parse anything.  There is also a fair chance you will run into an NRE late in the loop

Comment: Order by date descending and then take first value.

Comment: i am ordering the column but it consider it a string so its ordering by days and not by the date, like 01/01/1000 will be more recent than 30/02/2017 for the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not fetch the date straight from the source for the `datagridview`, presumably a `datatable` or `dataset` ? If the underlying data changes later for example due to user input, the datatable can trigger an **event**, so you can refresh the textbox.

The loop is totally unnecessary, so is the parsing and conversion. If you have valid datetime values they can easily be sorted.

Also, you are assuming that the date will always be in a certain column but the user could drag columns and change the display order, and your code will crash miserably.

So instead of:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

you can have:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[datagridview1.Columns["colDate"].Index].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

(not tested but should be very close if not correct)

Each column in the datagrid is an **control**, and hopefully you've given them **meaningful column names** (in this example: `colDate`).

You could fetch the max date from your datatable using the [DataTable.Compute function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=netframework-4.8) like:

```
table.Compute("MAX([DateColumn 1])", "");
```

(Do handle the case the datatable is empty, or expect the return value to be null)

Other alternatives: use the `DataTable.Select` function or **LINQ**.

Comment: the datagridview is not edited by the user, it is created by pasting an excel into that, and in this case the dates will always be on the column 14, so how can i fetch the column into a datatable?

Answer (score 0):

i found another...incredibly brute and unelagent solution, since i do not care how the interface looks and as a noob i know very little of dataset etc i have created three datagrid with the one column for days one for months and one for years.
the script then sort by year, the ones on top with the same year go into the second datagridview and are sorted by month, and the script repeat for the day, in the end the first row of the last datagris contain the most recent date.
As said this is incredibly brutish and could seems a neanderthalian solution...but it worked.

```
 for (int i2 = 0; i2 < date.Rows.Count; i2++)
        {
            int inizio = Int32.Parse(date.Rows[i2].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            int fine = Int32.Parse(date.Rows[i2].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            for (int i = inizio; i < fine; i++)
            {
                dataSortingGrid.Rows.Add();
                int startIndex = 0;
                int length = 2;
                string dataIntera = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
                int i3 = dataSortingGrid.Rows.Count - 1;
                String giorni = dataIntera.Substring(startIndex, length);
                dataSortingGrid.Rows[i3].Cells[0].Value = giorni;
                startIndex = 3;
                length = 2;
                String mesi = dataIntera.Substring(startIndex, length);
                dataSortingGrid.Rows[i3].Cells[1].Value = mesi;
                startIndex = 6;
                length = 4;
                String anni = dataIntera.Substring(startIndex, length);
                dataSortingGrid.Rows[i3].Cells[2].Value = anni;
                dataSortingGrid.Rows[i3].Cells[3].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[14].Value.ToString();
            }
            dataSortingGrid.Sort(dataSortingGrid.Columns[2], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
            //mesi

            int nRowMesi = Int32.Parse(dataSortingGrid.Rows.Count.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < nRowMesi; i++)
            {
                if (i < 1)
                {
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows.Add();
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;

                }
                else
                {
                    int valoreAnniSopra = Convert.ToInt32(dataSortingGrid.Rows[i - 1].Cells[2].Value);
                    int valoreAnniSotto = Convert.ToInt32(dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    if (valoreAnniSotto < valoreAnniSopra)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows.Add();

                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dataSortingGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;

                }
            }
            dataSortingGridMesi.Sort(dataSortingGridMesi.Columns[1], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending);

            //giorni

            int nRowGiorni = Int32.Parse(dataSortingGridMesi.Rows.Count.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < nRowGiorni; i++)
            {
                if (i < 1)
                {
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows.Add();
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;

                }
                else
                {
                    int valoreMesiSopra = Convert.ToInt32(dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i - 1].Cells[1].Value);
                    int valoreMesiSotto = Convert.ToInt32(dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    if (valoreMesiSotto < valoreMesiSopra)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows.Add();

                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    dataSortingGridGiorni.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dataSortingGridMesi.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;

                }
            }
            dataSortingGridGiorni.Sort(dataSortingGridGiorni.Columns[0], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
```